# How to get the user token at runtime with Cors WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to get the token from a user right after of being generated. I make the request to my endpoint and I get the response with the token but throughout HTTP but I want at runtime if it is possible! Thats the base code.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hash))
{
  Claim claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, hash);
  Claim gg = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Role");
  Claim[] claims = new Claim[] { claim, gg };               
  ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
  claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
  await base.OnGrantCustomExtension(c);
  c.Validated(claimsIdentity);          
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the method TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context) in your OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

[image]

Comment: Got it, but how I'm gonna call from `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` or `GrantCustomExtension` ?Thanks!

Comment: You dont need to call TokenEndpointResponse inside GrantResourceOwnerCredentials or GrantCustomExtension. 
The TokenEndpointResponse is always called before the TokenEndpoint redirects its response to the caller